# OpenCL: CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY on clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties (with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, opencl, gpgpu, amd-processor

I have a MSI Radeon R9 390X 8GB Video Card (named "Hawaii" as seen below). I have OpenCL installed on my Windows 10 Desktop, I am using Cygwin to compile and run the program.

I am trying to run an example OpenCL program I have kept around from a class from my college days, modified a little.

It won't run on my graphics card. Here is what I get:

```
$ ./ex26.exe -v 30 40
Bw=30 Bn=40 n=1200
OpenCL Platform 0: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 ----- OpenCL Device # 0: Hawaii-----
Gflops: 47.520000
Max Compute Units: 44
Max Clock Frequency: 1080
Total Memory of Device (bytes): 8589934592
Max Size of Memory Object Allocation (bytes): 4244635648
Max Work Group Size: 256

Fastest OpenCL Device: Hawaii
Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY
winnerPlatform: 140717488209200
```

You can see the code below to see where this error statements prints out. For whatever reason clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties is returning CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY. I don't understand how my CPU side memory could even be close to running out of memory to operate. I really don't know. Especially since all this method is doing is creating the queue.

In fact, if I switch CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU to CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU then the program executes without problem on the CPU.

It's all just on .cpp file. I couldn't really find anything to cut to make the MCV more minimal since it already an example so you are pretty the code you see if exactly what I have.

Here is all of the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/*
 *  Return elapsed wall time since last call (seconds)
 */
static double t0=0;
float Elapsed(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
   //  Windows version of wall time
   LARGE_INTEGER tv,freq;
   QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&tv);
   QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);
   double t = tv.QuadPart/(double)freq.QuadPart;
#else
   //  Unix/Linux/OSX version of wall time
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
   double t = tv.tv_sec+1e-6*tv.tv_usec;
#endif
   float s = t-t0;
   t0 = t;
   return s;
}

/*
 *  Print message to stderr and exit
 */
void Fatal(const char* format , ...)
{
   va_list args;
   va_start(args,format);
   vfprintf(stderr,format,args);
   va_end(args);
   exit(1);
}

/*
 *  Initialize matrix with random values
 */
void RandomInit(float x[],const unsigned int n)
{
   for (unsigned int i=0;i<n*n;i++)
      x[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

/*
 *  OpenCL notify callback (echo to stderr)
 */
void Notify(const char* errinfo,const void* private_info,size_t cb,void* user_data)
{
   fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",errinfo);
}


class ErrorReader {

public:

private:

};

/*
 *  Initialize fastest OpenCL device
 */
cl_device_id _DEV_ID;
cl_context _CONTEXT;
cl_command_queue _QUEUE;
int InitGPU(int verbose)
{
   cl_uint Nplat;
   cl_int  err;
   char name[1024];
   int  MaxGflops = -1;

   cl_platform_id winnerPlatform = 0;

   // Get platforms
   cl_platform_id platforms[8];
   if (clGetPlatformIDs(8, platforms, &Nplat)) Fatal("Cannot get number of OpenCL platforms\n");
   else if (Nplat<1) Fatal("No OpenCL platforms found\n");

   // Loop over platforms
   for (unsigned int platform = 0; platform < Nplat; platform++) {

      if (clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[platform], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sizeof(name), name, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL platform name\n");
      if (verbose) printf("OpenCL Platform %d: %s\n", platform, name);

      // Get GPU device IDs
      cl_uint Ndev;
      cl_device_id id[1024];
      if (clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[platform], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1024, id, &Ndev))
         Fatal("Cannot get number of OpenCL devices\n");
      else if (Ndev<1)
         Fatal("No OpenCL devices found\n");

      // Find the fastest device
      for (unsigned int devId = 0; devId < Ndev; devId++) {

         cl_uint compUnits, freq;
         cl_ulong memSize, maxAlloc;
         size_t maxWorkGrps;

         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(compUnits), &compUnits, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device units\n");
         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(freq), &freq, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device frequency\n");
         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(name), name, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device name\n");

         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(memSize), &memSize, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL memory size.\n");
         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, sizeof(memSize), &maxAlloc, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL memory size.\n");

         if (clGetDeviceInfo(id[devId], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(maxWorkGrps), &maxWorkGrps, NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL max work group size\n");

         int Gflops = compUnits * freq;

         if (verbose) printf(" ----- OpenCL Device # %d: %s-----\n"
           "Gflops: %f\n"
           "Max Compute Units: %d\n"
           "Max Clock Frequency: %d\n"
           "Total Memory of Device (bytes): %lu\n"
           "Max Size of Memory Object Allocation (bytes): %lu\n"
           "Max Work Group Size: %zu\n\n",
           devId,
           name,
           1e-3*Gflops,
           compUnits,
           freq,
           memSize,
           maxAlloc,
           maxWorkGrps);

         if (Gflops > MaxGflops)
         {
            _DEV_ID = id[devId];
            MaxGflops = Gflops;

            winnerPlatform = platforms[platform];
         }
      }
   }

   //  Print fastest device info
   if (clGetDeviceInfo(_DEV_ID,CL_DEVICE_NAME,sizeof(name),name,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device name\n");
   printf("Fastest OpenCL Device: %s\n",name);

   //  Check thread count
   size_t mwgs;
   if (clGetDeviceInfo(_DEV_ID,CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,sizeof(mwgs),&mwgs,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL max work group size\n");

   printf("winnerPlatform: %zu", winnerPlatform);

   // cl_platform_id platform = NULL;
   // int retValue = GetPlatform(&platform, winnerPlatform, true);

   //  Create OpenCL _CONTEXT for fastest device
   // _CONTEXT = clCreateContext(0,1,&_DEV_ID,Notify,NULL,&err);
   cl_context_properties cps[3] =
   {
      CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
      (cl_context_properties)winnerPlatform,
      (cl_context_properties)0
   };
   _CONTEXT = clCreateContextFromType(cps,
      CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &err);

   if (!_CONTEXT || err) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL Context\n");

   cl_command_queue_properties *propers;

   cl_command_queue_properties prop = 0;
   //prop |= CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;
   //prop |= CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE;

   propers = &prop;

   _QUEUE = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(_CONTEXT, _DEV_ID, propers, &err); //  Create OpenCL command _QUEUE for fastest device
   if (err) { 
      if (err == CL_INVALID_CONTEXT) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_INVALID_CONTEXT\n");
      else if (err == CL_INVALID_DEVICE) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_INVALID_DEVICE\n");
      else if (err == CL_INVALID_VALUE) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_INVALID_VALUE\n");
      else if (err == CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES\n");
      else if (err == CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY\n");
      else Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: ???????????? Unknown Error\n");
   } else if (!_QUEUE) {
      Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue: NULL\n");
   }

   return mwgs;
} 

/*
 * C = A * B -- host
 */
void AxBh(float C[], const float A[], const float B[], unsigned int n)
{
   for (unsigned int i=0;i<n;i++)
      for (unsigned int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         double sum=0;
         for (unsigned int k=0;k<n;k++)
            sum += (double)A[i*n+k] * (double)B[k*n+j];
         C[i*n+j] = (float)sum;
      }
}

/*
* Compute one element of A * B
*/
const char* source =
  "__kernel void AxB(__global float C[],__global const float A[],__global const float B[],const unsigned int n)\n"
  "{\n"
  "   unsigned int j = get_global_id(0);\n"
  "   unsigned int i = get_global_id(1);\n"
  "   float sum =0;\n"
  "   for (int k=0;k<n;k++)\n"
  "      sum += A[i*n+k] * B[k*n+j];\n"
  "   C[i*n+j] = sum;\n"
  "}\n";

/*
 * C = A * B -- device
 */
void AxBd(float Ch[],float Ah[],float Bh[],const unsigned int Bw,const unsigned int Bn)
{
   //  Calculate matrix dimensions
   int n = Bw*Bn;
   int N = n*n*sizeof(float);

   // Allocate device memory and copy A&B from host to device
   cl_int  err;
   cl_mem Ad = clCreateBuffer(_CONTEXT, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_USE_PERSISTENT_MEM_AMD, N, Ah, &err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create and copy A from host to device\n");
   cl_mem Bd = clCreateBuffer(_CONTEXT, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_USE_PERSISTENT_MEM_AMD, N, Bh, &err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create and copy B from host to device\n");

   //  Allocate device memory for C on device
   cl_mem Cd = clCreateBuffer(_CONTEXT,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,N,NULL,&err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create C on device\n");

   //  Compile kernel
   cl_program prog = clCreateProgramWithSource(_CONTEXT,1,&source,0,&err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create program\n");
   if (clBuildProgram(prog,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL))
   {
      char log[1048576];
      if (clGetProgramBuildInfo(prog,_DEV_ID,CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,sizeof(log),log,NULL))
         Fatal("Cannot get build log\n");
      else
         Fatal("Cannot build program\n%s\n",log);
   }
   cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(prog,"AxB",&err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create kernel\n");

   //  Set parameters for kernel
   if (clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&Cd)) Fatal("Cannot set kernel parameter Cd\n");
   if (clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),&Ad)) Fatal("Cannot set kernel parameter Ad\n");
   if (clSetKernelArg(kernel,2,sizeof(cl_mem),&Bd)) Fatal("Cannot set kernel parameter Bd\n");
   if (clSetKernelArg(kernel,3,sizeof(int),&n)) Fatal("Cannot set kernel parameter n\n");

   //  Run kernel
   size_t Global[2] = {(size_t)n, (size_t)n};
   size_t Local[2]  = {(size_t)Bw, (size_t)Bw};
   if (clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(_QUEUE,kernel,2,NULL,Global,Local,0,NULL,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot run kernel\n");

   //  Release kernel and program
   if (clReleaseKernel(kernel)) Fatal("Cannot release kernel\n");
   if (clReleaseProgram(prog)) Fatal("Cannot release program\n");

   // Copy C from device to host (block until done)
   if (clEnqueueReadBuffer(_QUEUE,Cd,CL_TRUE,0,N,Ch,0,NULL,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot copy C from device to host\n");

   //  Free device memory
   clReleaseMemObject(Ad);
   clReleaseMemObject(Bd);
   clReleaseMemObject(Cd);
}

/*
 *  main
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   //  Process options
   int opt;
   int verbose=0;
   while ((opt=getopt(argc,argv,"v"))!=-1)
   {
      if (opt=='v')
         verbose++;
      else
         Fatal("Usage: [-v] <block width> <number of blocks>\n");
   }
   argc -= optind;
   argv += optind;

   //  Get width and number of blocks
   if (argc!=2) Fatal("Usage: [-v] <block width> <number of blocks>\n");
   int Bw = atoi(argv[0]);
   if (Bw<1) Fatal("Block width out of range %d\n",Bw);
   int Bn = atoi(argv[1]);
   if (Bn<1) Fatal("Number of blocks out of range %d\n",Bn);
   //  Total width is block times number of blocks
   int n = Bw*Bn;
   int N = n*n*sizeof(float);
   printf("Bw=%d Bn=%d n=%d\n",Bw,Bn,n);

   //  Initialize GPU
   int Mw = InitGPU(verbose);
   if (Mw<Bw*Bw) Fatal("Thread count %d exceeds max work group size of %d\n",Bw*Bw,Mw);

   // Allocate host matrices A/B/C/R
   float* Ah = (float*)malloc(N);
   float* Bh = (float*)malloc(N);
   float* Ch = (float*)malloc(N);
   float* Rh = (float*)malloc(N);
   if (!Ah || !Bh || !Ch || !Rh) Fatal("Cannot allocate host memory\n");

   // Initialize A & B
   srand(9999);
   RandomInit(Ah,n);
   RandomInit(Bh,n);

   //  Compute R = AB on host
   Elapsed();
   AxBh(Rh,Ah,Bh,n);
   float Th = Elapsed();

   //  Compute C = AB on device
   Elapsed();
   AxBd(Ch,Ah,Bh,Bw,Bn);
   float Td = Elapsed();

   //  Compute difference between R and C
   double r2=0;
   for (int i=0;i<n*n;i++)
      r2 += fabs(Ch[i]-Rh[i]);
   r2 /= n*n;

   //  Free host memory
   free(Ah);
   free(Bh);
   free(Ch);
   free(Rh);

   //  Print results
   printf("Host   Time = %6.3f s\n",Th);
   printf("Device Time = %6.3f s\n",Td);
   printf("Speedup = %.1f\n",Th/Td);
   printf("Difference = %.2e\n",r2);

   //  Done
   return 0;
}
```

I compile it using (which you will obviously have to alter a little):

> g++ -Wall -o exMatrixMult -I"/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP SDK/3.0/include" -L"/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP SDK/3.0/lib/x86_64" exMatrixMult.cpp -lOpenCL

My "Hawaii" graphics card can, however, run the example programs that came with the OpenCL SDK (in "AMD APP SDK\3.0\samples\opencl\bin\x86_64"). I spent most of the afternoon to see how their source code differs from mine, no success so far.

If at all useful the code where the error occurs use to look like this (same problem still occurred):

```
   //  Print fastest device info
   if (clGetDeviceInfo(devid,CL_DEVICE_NAME,sizeof(name),name,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL device name\n");
   printf("Fastest OpenCL Device: %s\n",name);

   //  Check thread count
   size_t mwgs;
   if (clGetDeviceInfo(devid,CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,sizeof(mwgs),&mwgs,NULL)) Fatal("Cannot get OpenCL max work group size\n");

   //  Create OpenCL context for fastest device
   context = clCreateContext(0,1,&devid,Notify,NULL,&err);
   if(!context || err) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL context\n");

   //  Create OpenCL command queue for fastest device
   queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, devid, 0, &err);
   if (err) Fatal("Cannot create OpenCL command cue\n");
```

Now the problem may not be verifiable if you don't have a similar graphics card. But I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away when I updated my graphics card's driver.